# How get products id without default 0 if product has attribute

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop

I want to get records from table ps_stock_available without default "0" attribute if product has attribute. As you know in ps_stock_available table show's default attribute as 0
for example ...
`id_product id_product_attribute
     1              0
     1              12
     1              13
     1              14
     2              0
     3              0
     4              0
     4              1
     4              2
     4              4`

What i want is to get records by mysql query such as

`id_product id_product_attribute
    1                12
    1                13
    1                14
    2                0
    3                0
    4                1
    4                2
    4                4`

Let me know if someone can help.

Comment: How far did you get? What did you try?

Comment: Its a very long query. I just stuck on that step to get my desire result.

Comment: It helps us considerably if we can see how far you've got. Often it's a tiny thing we can point out to fix. Saves us having to re-implement what you've already done.

Comment: what i want is just to filter records of duplicate p_id with none 0 in att_id and single p_id with 0 att_id thats it.

Answer (score 0):

on possible way to do this.

```
select * from tbl_name
  where ((p_id in (205, 206) and att_id != 0) 
     or (att_id = 0 and !(p_id = 205 or p_id=206)));
```

Comment: thanks brain but i have thousand of records in that table not only 205 and 206.